# Adding Autotrack.js to affiliate sites--will it affect analytics if their main site does not use autotrack

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to add autotrack.js to affiliate quote forms hosted on my site. However, I do not how it will affect affiliate websites that do not use autotrack.

I read that "Autotrack is not an official Google Analytics product and does not qualify for GA Premium".

Will it harm my affiliates in any way to have the autotrack on their quote form? It will have their GA website tracking number.

Answer (score 0):

If you use their tracking ID you will be sending additional hits to their account (with metrics they might not have on their main site), so to that extent it will affect their tracking.  It will not stop their tracking from working, if that's what you worry about.

And about the disclaimer, it says that the autotrack plugins do not qualify for "qualify for GA Premium **support**". I'm sure they will work with GA Premium just fine (which after all uses the same tracking code), but GA support will not help you with any problems you may encounter.

Comment: So essentially, they will just have more info in their Google Analytics. Thanks for responding.